# Is the time machine that Paracelsus uses powered by a flux capacitor?

Tags: back-to-the-future, warehouse-13, flux-capacitor

In the first episode of the fifth season of Warehouse 13, Paracelsus uses H.G. wells's time machine, and by connecting several artefacts to it, he can actually travel through time, rather than just send his conciousness. In a close-up of the time machine, a coil looking suspiciously similar to the flux capacitor from the Back to the Future trilogy is shown.

[image: Time machine coil Warehouse 13]

[image: Back to the Future flux capacitor]

Is this just a nod to Back to the Future, or does it hint that, in the Warehouse 13 universe, the events of Back to the Future actually happened, and that the flux capacitor was either snagged or recreated. I'm leaning heavily towards the former, but does anyone know for sure? I guess it's also possible that this is just coincidence, but I doubt that is the case.